# How to get current User outside a Controller in Web API .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to get the current User from the Context outside a controller in my Web API. I'm using the OpenIddict to authenticate users, so the authorization is made by tokens.

I have registered the HttpContextAcessor as a singleton in my Startup.cs:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

After that, I inject the HttpContexrAcessor in my hub, like this:

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
    {
        private IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
        private HttpContext _context { get { return _contextAccessor.HttpContext; } }

        public NotificationHub(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
        {
            _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        }

        public async Task JoinGroup()
        {
            Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, $"notification_{_context.User.Identity.Name}");
        }

        public void Send(JsonResult notification)
        {
                Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).sendNotification(notification);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that _context.User.Identity.Name is always null.

Is there some way to do that?

Comment: Accessing HttpContext outside the request pipeline is a recipe for disaster.  If your class needs `User.Identity.Name` then *construct it with that data passed in*. If you don't have access to something like `User.Identity.Name` when you're constructing your class, it's very unlikely you will have access to the static `HttpContext` within your class, anyways.

Comment: @ChrisPratt the problem is that I need to map the User with the ConnectionID of the Hub or to insert the user in a Group of the hub where the User will be the only member. In the case of the notification, it will be sent from a controller, using the HubContext, so I need to send it just to ONE user.

Comment: If you're sending it from the controller, then you have the opportunity to pass the user at that point. It's more appropriate to interact the active user where it exists. If your setup doesn't accommodate doing it then, that's a design issue.

Comment: @ChrisPratt yes, but It's not possible to get the Hub ConnectionID from a Controller, so I can't send the notification by a ConnectionID neither insert the user in a Group, since it also needs the connectionid to be done.

Comment: Again, design issue. The "Hub ConnectionID" should be injected into whatever class needs it, then. In other words, you're most likely conflating too much in a single class. Remember SOLID, classes should encapsulate discrete units of functionality (do one thing, and do it well). Needing dependencies that aren't all available at the same time is a sign that your class is failing at that.

Comment: @ChrisPratt ok, but the only way to deal with the HubContext in a Controller, is injecting the IConnectionManager, right? Using the connection manager is not possible to retrieve the connection id. I thought that the best was mapping the User and te Connection ID inside the Hub, but I'm not sure about it now. I'm a little confused.

Comment: Inside your controller, in any action that "should" have the user logged in. Can you try and see what is inside HttpContext.User.Identity.Name. The property HttpContext is available in any controller for use. That will tell you whether this is an injection issue, or you just don't have the name set anyway.

Comment: @MindingData I think you don't understand the question. Yes, inside an Action It's possible to get the User information, but I can't get their Hub ConnectionID. To add a User in a Hub Group, It's necessary to have the user connection ID. On the other hand, inside the Hub, I have the Connection ID, but don't have the User's information, like the Username.

Answer (score 4):

In my case using .Net Core 2.0, where I needed to get the User Id outside the controller, in Application Service, I did the following:

in **Startup.cs** I added this line under **ConfigureServices**

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

I created the following class

```
public class UserResolverService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public UserResolverService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _httpContext = httpContext;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public string GetUserId()
    {
        var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(_httpContext.HttpContext.User);
        return userId;
    }
}
```

In my **Application Service** class, I called the **UserResolverService**

```
public class MyApplicationService
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly UserResolverService _userResolverService;

    public MyApplicationService(ApplicationDbContext context, UserResolverService userResolverService)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userResolverService = userResolverService;
    }

    public async Task Create(MyModel entity)
    {
        entity.CreatorUserId = _userResolverService.GetUserId();
        _context.MyModel.Add(entity);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Also, if you don't want to user the **UserManager**, you can simply make the **UserResolverService** class like this:

```
public class UserResolverService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;

    public UserResolverService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
    {
        _httpContext = httpContext;
    }
    public string GetUserId()
    {
        var user = _httpContext?.HttpContext?.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
        var userId = user.Claims.ElementAt(0).Value;
        return userId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal(v=vs.110).aspx

`System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal`

Comment: Not only may this be changed by any 3rd party library (since it's mutable) it also may not be set after any async calls.  pretty dangerous.

Answer (score -2):

Try removing this line from your startup:

`services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`

I believe the framework already registers that for you.

Answer (score -10):

Try This:

```cs
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: That's definitely not the answer.